# Programmatically adding a view as a menu item

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a navigation drawer and I would like to add a view (Button, etc) to the menu. I don't want to use XML, therefore I am not using an inflator. I tried the setActionView method based on these examples at https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.view.MenuItem/setActionView but I am getting an empty menu. Is what I am trying to do is possible? Here is my relevant part of code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add("search");
    SearchView sv = new SearchView(this);
    item.setActionView(sv);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ITEM1 = 1;
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ITEM1, Menu.NONE, "Item name");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_ITEM_ITEM1:
        //your action       
       return true;

    default:
        return false;
  }
}
```